# EntityClient Provider - What exactly does it do?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I created a new MVC application and added an Entity Framework model generated from the NerdDinner database.

I looked at the connectionStrings section of my web.config and was confused at the connection string that it created:

```
<add name="NerdDinnerEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.NerdDinner.csdl|res://*/Models.NerdDinner.ssdl|res://*/Models.NerdDinner.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=TINCTOM;Initial Catalog=NerdDinner;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

What exactly does each piece of the connection string do? I don't really know much about the Entity Framework and was just trying to mess around with it to learn a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote [a detailed examination of the connection strings](http://www.craigstuntz.com/posts/2010-08-13-troubleshooting-entity-framework-connection-strings.html) which explains the options for the metadata.

Comment: Thanks this helped. Can you recommend any starting points for learning more about Entity Framework (specifically 4) in general?

Comment: You have written quite nice blog. It will be really great for the readers and the OP if you can reproduce some important parts of your blog in this post itself. Links can get broken in the future making post context-less.

Comment: @CraigStuntz This link no longer works; time permitting, would you please update your link or rewrite your answer to include the linked content? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the details about each piece from the connection string http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx

Comment: It will be really great for the readers and the OP if you can reproduce some important parts of the link in this post itself. Links can get broken in the future making your post context-less.